Spring boot autoconfiguration from a generated source
I'm in the process of creating a custom openapi-generator, to auto generate configuration properties and (hopefully) AutoConfiguration.
I have it generating everything into target/generated-sources/demo-client.
It generates the following structure:
└── src
    └── main
        ├── AndroidManifest.xml
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── demo
        │           └── custom
        │               ├── ApiClient.java
        │               ├── ...
        │               ├── api
        │               │   ├── PetApi.java
        │               │   ├── StoreApi.java
        │               │   └── UserApi.java
        │               ├── config
        │               │   ├── DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration.java
        │               │   └── DemoApiProperties.java
        │               └── model
        │                   ├── Address.java
        │                   └── ...
        └── resources
            └── META-INF
                ├── spring
                │   └── org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports
                └── spring.factories

And the classes are as follows:
DemoApiProperties.java:
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("m2m.demo")
public class DemoApiProperties {

    private String baseUrl = "demo-service";

    public String getBaseUrl() {
        return baseUrl;
    }

    public void setBaseUrl(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

}

DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration.java:
@AutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnProperty("m2m.demo.base-url")
public class DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ApiClient demoM2mApiClient(RestClient m2mRestClient, DemoPackageApiProperties apiProperties) {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(demoM2mApiClient);
        apiClient.setBasePath(apiProperties.getBaseUrl());
        return apiClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public PetApi petApi(ApiClient demoM2mApiClient) {
        return new PetApi(demoM2mApiClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public StoreApi storeApi(ApiClient demoM2mApiClient) {
        return new StoreApi(demoM2mApiClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserApi userApi(ApiClient demoM2mApiClient) {
        return new UserApi(demoM2mApiClient);
    }


}

And then the META-INF files:
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports
com.demo.custom.config.DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration

And as you can see I've even tried in the spring boot two way, using spring.factories
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.demo.custom.config.DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration

But whenever I start the application it is not finding the DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration so it isn't processing it, from looking at the debug logs Spring Boot isn't discovering that this AutoConfiguration exists.
If I update my application to use Imports it works fine:
// this is exactly the same class as whats in the AutoConfiguration imports
import com.demo.custom.config.DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration; 

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({
  DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class MyServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeeEngineApplication.class, args);
    }

}


I am using Spring Boot 3.4.0.
Is it possible for Spring to pickup generated-sources AutoConfiguration's? It's not the end of the world if we have to use @Import, would just be nice to remove that extra verbosity.

I think you are missing the EnableConfigurationProperties Annotation on the Autoconfiguration class.
It should be:
@AutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnProperty("m2m.demo.base-url")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DemoApiProperties.class)
public class DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ApiClient demoM2mApiClient(RestClient m2mRestClient, DemoPackageApiProperties apiProperties) {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(demoM2mApiClient);
        apiClient.setBasePath(apiProperties.getBaseUrl());
        return apiClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public PetApi petApi(ApiClient demoM2mApiClient) {
        return new PetApi(demoM2mApiClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public StoreApi storeApi(ApiClient demoM2mApiClient) {
        return new StoreApi(demoM2mApiClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserApi userApi(ApiClient demoM2mApiClient) {
        return new UserApi(demoM2mApiClient);
    }

Be sure to have the property m2m.demo.base-url in your configuration file in order for this to work, i would also recommend to change that and add a boolean property to enable/disable the configuration and use it instead of the url.

Spring boot 3.x autoconfiguration doc
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/developing-auto-configuration.html#features.developing-auto-configuration
in short: don't use META-INF/spring.factories but META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports

Gave this a go, and interestingly if I still use @Import(DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration.class) spring now complains there are  2 DemoApiProperties  beans, but if I remove it then it there are still zero PetApi ones so this unfortunately doesn't work.

can you remove the @Component from DemoApiProperties ?
it would be better if you show us some screenshots

I've tried all variations with/without @Component. I think the issue is Spring doesn't search for @AutoConfiguration classes in the /target directory.
I don't know what you'd expect to see in a screenshot, all I can tell you is from enabling debug logs for org.springframework there is no AutoConfiguration logged for DemoApiClientAutoConfiguration which suggests isn't Spring isn't automatically picking this up, for whatever reason that may be
